# ISSUES RELATED TO DPDK

Tags: networking

I am trying to apply Data Plane Development Kit to allow an Network Card to forward data received by one port through another port, but Data Plane Development Kit is completely new to me. Thus, I am wondering what should I do to configure it to fulfill my request.

Answer (score 1):

One can start using DPDK libraries in 2 modes

1. Physcial NIC
2. Virtual NIC

As mentioned since you are using Physcial NIC, I recommend first to check [DPDK Supported CPU and NIC](http://core.dpdk.org/supported/) and ensure you have right devices. If you do not have a physical you can fall back to virtual NIC like PCAP/TAP (L2), TUN (L3), or KNI. Based on the route forward rules you can then redirect the valid packet from DPDK to any non DPDK physical interface.

Recommend reading

- start with [step 1](http://core.dpdk.org/doc/quick-start/).
- [DPDK driver bind and unbind](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/linux_drivers.html#binding-and-unbinding-network-ports-to-from-the-kernel-modules).
- [sample reference application](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/skeleton.html)